I want to Understanding the Start and End Points of Trace Spans in OpenTelemetry Python
I'm trying to understand where exactly the trace spans are created and ended when using the OpenTelemetry instrumentation for Python. Specifically, I would like to know:
For inbound requests (e.g. HTTP requests), where in the code does the trace span start and end?
For outbound requests (e.g. HTTP client calls, database queries), where does the span start before the outgoing call and end after the response is received?
For local function calls within the application, how are the span boundaries determined and instrumented?
It would be really helpful if you could provide some insights or point me to the relevant parts of the codebase that handle span creation and completion. Understanding the precise span boundaries is important for me to correctly interpret the trace data and identify performance bottlenecks.
Any guidance or documentation references would be much appreciated. Thank you!
I'm struggling to understand how to instrument tracing data, especially the starting and ending points of traces. While I've tried examining the source code, it's difficult for me to grasp. I've been thinking about trying to manually add spans to understand the differences compared to using auto-instrumentation

Autoinstrumentation is just monkeypatching with wrappers that call the OpenTelemetry SDK. Most (all?) of the public instrumentation lives at https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python-contrib/tree/main/instrumentation. I found the Jinja2 instrumentation to be pretty simple to adapt for my own library. I just copied the opentelemetry-instrumentation-jinja2 folder to opentelemetry-instrumentation-mylibrary, and changed module names within. If you are OK with adding OpenTelemetry dependencies to your code, maybe https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/python/instrumentation/ would be more straightforward. The auto-instrumentation is pretty clean, though.
